# How to switch loading indicator as default base on device ( Andriod show circularprogressindicator and IOS show CupertinoActivityIndicator)?

Tags: ios, flutter, loading, indicator

How to switch loading indicator as default base on device ( Andriod show circularprogressindicator and IOS show CupertinoActivityIndicator)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by creating your own widget. Flutter does it for [BackButtonIcon](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7e9793dee1/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/back_button.dart#L25) widget.

I just got the code from it and modifying it for you to use :) All you need to do is to use `LoadingIndicator()` where you need it.

```
class LoadingIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoadingIndicator({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  /// Returns the appropriate "loading indicator" icon for the given `platform`.
  Widget _getIndicatorWidget(TargetPlatform platform) {
    switch (platform) {
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        return const CupertinoActivityIndicator();
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
      default:
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      _getIndicatorWidget(Theme.of(context).platform);
}
```